# Upgrading Stack on NixOS

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, nixos

**Problem:** I am trying to upgrade haskell `stack` from version `1.4.0` to `.1.5.1` in NixOS.

In my `configuration.nix`:

```
environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
  # ...
  stack
  # ...
];
```

On `nixpkgs`, it says that stack should be on version `1.5.1`:

[image]

Yet:

```
$ stack --version
Version 1.4.0 x86_64
```

Comment: What nix-channel are you on? Is it updated?

Comment: `$ nix-shell -p stack -I nixpkgs=https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/master.tar.gz` if you want to living on the edge. (`-I` flag also work on `nix-env`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packages listed on https://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html reflect the current stable release of NixOS, which is currently 17.09.

Stack 1.5.1 became available on that very same release, 17.09. To install Stack 1.5.1 you need to be either on the NixOS unstable branch or on NixOS 17.09. It seems you're currently on NixOS 17.03.